# How can you get a list of running Python scripts?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to populate a list with all currently executing python scripts' file paths - how could this be done in Python?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Not exclusively in python -- a python script has no way of knowing what other processes are running without inquiring the OS.  What OS(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Every script you run is a separate process. If you want to find out what processes are running you need to reach into your OS API.

Comment: Right interesting, Windows, so would it be possible to use win32api?

Comment: @Kugel I had a look in the task manager, they all run under the interpreter which is always python.exe

Comment: @James true. But it's always a separate instance of python.exe. You can launch multiple notepad.exe instances as well.

Comment: Okay, I'm worried this is becoming yucky - it would involve getting arguments sent to the python.exes to find out which .py it was given. mmm.

Comment: @James Not always python.exe - pythonw.exe is possible as well.

Comment: @James What if it was an interpreter and not a file running too? I think the closest you would get is overriding one of the python packages, but that's really ugly...

Comment: @jadkik94: Or use `sitecustomize.py`, perhaps.

Comment: Another question is, when you say "currently executing", if your program spans multiple files, would you expect it to tell you the file that was run to kick off the process, the file the code that was currently executing was in, or a stack trace?  And what if the script you launched subsequently launched subprocesses, how would you want that reported?

Comment: @sr2222 That's true, more complicated than I thought. I'm going to give up and use another approach to the issue that required the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [found a nice utility](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) that may help you. Never used it before personally.

Install with pip:

```
pip install psutil
```

Play around:

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.get_process_list():
    if 'python' in p.name:
        print p.cmdline
```

`cmdline` should gave you the arguments that python interpreter was started with. That may get you some of your cases.

Comment: output: `NameError: name 'name' is not defined.`

Comment: I no longer need the list for the problem I am personally solving so I thought I'd mark this as the answer because it looks the closest. Thanks everyone. I've +1 all answers.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to make `p.name` a string and convert to lowercase to get this to work properly like so: `if 'python' in str(p.name).lower()`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library is the correct answer to every question that relates to dealing with processes(and even more if you want to have something that is platform-independent).

In particular you are interested in [this](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Processes) functions that allows you to list all processes, which you can then filter using `Process.name`/`exe`/`cmdline`obtaining the list of python processes' cmdlines.

Comment: The latest psutil docs are [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#functions), as the above link is long outdated.